# C: How to find size of array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am currently learning C and I have a problem on how to find the size of array. As for string, I have a pointer pointing to the beginning of the string, and then I continuously looking if there are any '\0'. If there is one, then it stop. 
For example:

```
char string[] = {'h', 'i', '\0', 'q', 'a'}; 
printf("%s", string);
```

Instead of showing 'hi\0qa', it shows 'hi'.

However, how do I know the size of an array? I have searched it for a while and most of the answers are something like this:

```
int numArray[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
printf("%d", sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(int));
```

I understand how it works. However, in this way, we will always get the array size as 10. This makes sense, since memory is allocated for storing 10 integer values in the numArray.

But what I really want, is NOT 10, but 5. So how can I get this value instead? Thanks.

Comment: `int numArray[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; ` is the same as `int numArray[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`. So the array size *is* 10.

Comment: How will you distinguish between the end of the "valid" entries and default initialized or uninitialized entries?

Comment: @Jongware Not a duplicate. Note the last two paragraphs.

Comment: @this: Whatever. It must be a duplicate of dozens of questions, I just picked one at random. Which strongly smells like OP did not attempt a search.

Comment: @Jongware *Whatever* is not a legitimate reason. Please reevaluate your voting habits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C arrays don't have *exact number of elements* property, so you'll have to keep this piece of information yourself and update it appropriately. For example, you could define a struct like this:

```
struct ArrayWrapper
{
    int an_array[100];
    unsigned int num_of_elements;
};
```

You could also write some methods to manipulate such object, like AddElement, RemoveElement (decrements num_of_elements) and so on.

Comment: thanks... in this way... I think I can get the answer I want

Answer (score 1):

You can't - C has no language support for this. Conventionally, you have a couple of options:

- Keep track of the length of the data yourself.
- Add a "sentinel value" to the end of the array so that you can tell where it is. C strings are an example of this, as they end in the character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` gives you the number of bytes of an array. `sizeof(array)/sizeof(type)` gives you the number of elements of an array.

Sizeof only woks for statically declared arrays, that is, the size is known at compile time. For example `int myArray[10]` where the 10 is "statically declared".

What you ask is to know the size of an array in use. You give it 10 elements but only use 5. You will have to keep track of that yourself.

By the way, a string (array of characters) in C as defined as all characters up to the first `\0` (null character). Therefore, printing `string` will only print "hi".

Answer (score 0):

When you ask computer to give you size of an array it can only give you that size which it knows, that is allocated in memory.
When you need size of array with non-zero elements then this is what would help

- Check size of array from computer
- Make sure that you know what condition you want to check to make an array element as a valid element to include in size
- Count all valid elements by iterating through the array by any mean
- Count of all valid elements is with you

Remember that computer has no idea that you want integers/strings or count of those values which are non-zero etc. That condition is subject to your rules.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VALUES {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

int main(void){
    int numArray[10] = VALUES; 
    printf("%d\n", (int)(sizeof((int[])VALUES)/sizeof(int))); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a really bad example of macro abuse, which can be completely replaced with a single variable.

Comment: `int numArray[10] = VALUES; ` --> `int numArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5};` Isn't this enough